# How to show xprofile data in member page and change member page in buddypress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to show xprofil data in members page.Like extra fields name Company Name,Phone,other data
also i want to change members page name.like
Members instead of School

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your pages so you can organize each field to be displayed however you want you can call each field individually with this..

```
<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=The Name Of The Field'); ?>
```

Note the spaces, `field=` should be the exact name you assigned it in *users -> profile fields* minus the (required) that is auto inserted after.

There is also a way to call all the xprofile data as a block but as I don't use that method I can't help you there.